# how to use Twist with Timer()

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, timer

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd like to make the robot moves a certain time toward x-direction using Twist with `Timer`

full code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import rospy
from geometry_msgs.msg import Twist
class GoForward():
    def __init__(self):
        rospy.init_node('GoForward', anonymous=False)
        rospy.on_shutdown(self.shutdown)
        self.cmd_vel = rospy.Publisher('/cmd_vel', Twist, queue_size=10)
        rospy.Timer(rospy.Duration(2), self.my_callback)
    def my_callback(self, event):
        move_cmd = Twist()
        move_cmd.linear.x = 0.2
        move_cmd.angular.z = 0
        self.cmd_vel.publish(move_cmd)
    def shutdown(self):
        rospy.loginfo("Stop TurtleBot")
        self.cmd_vel.publish(Twist())
        rospy.sleep(1)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        GoForward()
except:
    rospy.loginfo("GoForward node terminated.")
```

What is wrong, the code stops without continue.

any help or suggestions, it would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I modified the code to:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import rospy
from geometry_msgs.msg import Twist
class GoForward():
    def __init__(self):
        rospy.init_node('GoForward', anonymous=False)
        rospy.on_shutdown(self.shutdown)
        self.cmd_vel = rospy.Publisher('/cmd_vel', Twist, queue_size=10)
        event_period = rospy.get_param('~event_period', 0.02)
        rospy.Timer(rospy.Duration(event_period), self.my_callback)
    def my_callback(self, event):
        move_cmd = Twist()
        move_cmd.linear.x = 0.2
        move_cmd.angular.z = 0
        self.cmd_vel.publish(move_cmd)
    def shutdown(self):
        rospy.loginfo("Stop TurtleBot")
        self.cmd_vel.publish(Twist())
        rospy.sleep(1)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        GoForward()
        rospy.spin()
    except:
        rospy.loginfo("GoForward node terminated.")
```

the output:

the robot moved without stopping.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/339394/how-to-use-twist-with-timer()/) by [Redhwan](https://answers.ros.org/users/34008/redhwan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2019-12-07

Post score: -1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Don't know about the rest, but we see this:

> ```
> class GoForward():
> ```

```
    def __init__(self):
        ...
        rospy.Timer(rospy.Duration(2), self.my_callback)
```

you're not assigning the `Timer` to anything, causing the temporary object to go out of scope immediately and being destroyed.

So the `Timer` never really does anything.

You'll probably wan to do something like this:

```
self.my_timer = rospy.Timer(rospy.Duration(2), self.my_callback)
```

And the same issue here:

> ```
> if __name__ == '__main__':
> ```

```
    try:
        GoForward()
```

`GoForward` is not a function, but a `class`.

You're calling the constructor of the class, but don't store the returned object anywhere.

So your program creates an instance of `GoForward`, which is then immediately destroyed as it's not assigned to a variable in scope.

In the end, your program does nothing as it terminates immediately after calling the `GoForward` constructor and destroying the object.

You'll probably want to do something like this:

```
obj = GoForward()
```

And then also add this afterwards:

```
rospy.spin()
```

Because without it -- or something similar -- your program again exits immediately.

---

Edit: in your updated code, you:

1. still don't store the `Timer` in a member variable
2. still don't store the `GoForward` instance in a variable

Your script still has the same problems as the original version.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-12-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-12-07**:
Note: this is purely a Python problem. Not something ROS-specific.

**Comment by [Redhwan](https://answers.ros.org/users/34008/redhwan/) on 2019-12-08**:
Thanks for your help, it is not working yet.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-12-09**:
As always: if you want our help, you'll have to be much more specific.

We cannot help you if you just write: "it does not work" ..

**Comment by [Redhwan](https://answers.ros.org/users/34008/redhwan/) on 2019-12-09**:
sorry, @gvdhoorn  I will update in my question what I modified in the code.